# Print report with error REP-8: A run time error in the PL/SQL development environment (DE)

Tags: oracle, plsql, report

I have problem with generate report to PDF via Report Server. 
When generating a report show an error:

**REP-8: A run time error in the PL/SQL development environment (DE)
PDE-PSD001 Could not resolve reference to  while loading 
REP-0008: An unexpected memory error occurred while initializing preferences.**

The error occurs randomly. Once the report prints without problems and at a second printing report does not print and an error shown above, 
although the report contains the same data.

My report use 3 Ref cursors and 3 select query. Use Report builder version 11.1.2.2.0.

Please, knows anyone where the problem is and how to resolve it?

Here is example, how I call Ref cusrcor:
Package:

```
TYPE t_info_rec IS RECORD  (
     column_1           VARCHAR2(15)
    ,column_2           NUMBER
    ,column_3           DATE
    ,column_4           VARCHAR2(15)
    ,column_5           VARCHAR2(15)
  ); 

TYPE t_info_cur IS REF CURSOR RETURN t_info_rec;

PROCEDURE info(p_cur       IN OUT   t_info_cur
               ,p_parameter_1        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_2        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_3        VARCHAR2
               ,p_parameter_4        VARCHAR2
               ,p_parameter_5        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_6        VARCHAR2);
```

Package Body:

```
PROCEDURE info(p_cur       IN OUT   t_info_cur
               ,p_parameter_1        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_1        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_1        VARCHAR2
               ,p_parameter_1        VARCHAR2
               ,p_parameter_1        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_1        VARCHAR2)
  IS
    --
  BEGIN
    --
      OPEN p_cur FOR 
        SELECT column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4,column_5
            FROM table
            ;

    --
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE;
      open p_cur for SELECT null,null,null,null,null FROM dual WHERE 1=0;
  END info;
```

Call Ref cusrsor from Report Builders in RDF file:

```
function QR_2RefCurDS return package.t_info_cur is
  c1 package.t_info_cur;
begin

  package.info(c1
     ,p_parameter_1 =>  :P_PARAM1
     ,p_parameter_2 =>  :P_PARAM2
     ,p_parameter_3 =>  :P_PARAM3
     ,p_parameter_4 =>  :P_PARAM4
     ,p_parameter_5 =>  :P_PARAM5
     ,p_parameter_6 =>  :P_PARAM6
     );
  return c1;   
end;
```

I am sorry for my English.

Thank you

Standa

Answer (score 0):

There are few issue with your code. I can see that you declared type of ref cursor. Not sure if that can work. However without digging further in your code i show my code as below. In my code I am creating a record and passing the record type to procedure.

Solution 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Pkg_test
AS
   TYPE t_info_rec IS RECORD
   (
      column_1   NUMBER,
      column_2   NUMBER,
      column_3   VARCHAR2 (15),
      column_4   VARCHAR2 (15),
      column_5   NUMBER
   );

   TYPE t_info_cur IS TABLE OF t_info_rec;

   PROCEDURE info (p_cur           IN OUT t_info_cur,
                   p_parameter_1          NUMBER,
                   p_parameter_2          NUMBER,
                   p_parameter_3          VARCHAR2,
                   p_parameter_4          VARCHAR2,
                   p_parameter_5          NUMBER,
                   p_parameter_6          VARCHAR2);


   FUNCTION QR_2RefCurDS
      RETURN t_info_cur;
END Pkg_test;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY  Pkg_test 
as 
  PROCEDURE info(p_cur  IN  OUT   t_info_cur
               ,p_parameter_1        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_2        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_3        VARCHAR2
               ,p_parameter_4        VARCHAR2
               ,p_parameter_5        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_6        VARCHAR2)
  IS    
   BEGIN

      --OPEN p_cur FOR 
        SELECT p_parameter_1,p_parameter_2,p_parameter_3,p_parameter_4,p_parameter_5
        bulk collect into p_cur
        FROM dual   ;                        

   EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN      
      dbms_output.put_line('In exception');
     -- open p_cur for 
       SELECT null,null,null,null,null 
       bulk collect into p_cur
       FROM dual WHERE 1=0;

   End;          
  --Function Starting 
 FUNCTION QR_2RefCurDS 
 return t_info_cur 
 is
  c1  t_info_cur;   
 begin
   info(c1 
     ,p_parameter_1 =>  1         --:P_PARAM1
     ,p_parameter_2 =>  2         --:P_PARAM2
     ,p_parameter_3 =>  'Hello'   --:P_PARAM3
     ,p_parameter_4 =>  'Howru' --:P_PARAM4
     ,p_parameter_5 =>   4         --:P_PARAM5
     ,p_parameter_6 =>  'BYE'     --:P_PARAM6
     );
  return c1;     
end;

END Pkg_test;

/
```

Execution:

```
SQL> declare
    outpt PKG_TEST.t_info_cur;
    begin

     outpt:=PKG_TEST.QR_2RefCurDS;

     for i in 1..outpt.count
     loop
       dbms_output.put_line(outpt(i).column_1 ||'   ' || outpt(i).column_2||'   ' || outpt(i).column_3||'   ' || outpt(i).column_4||'   ' || outpt(i).column_5);     end loop;     
     end;
    /

    1   2   Hello   Howru   4    

   PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Solution 2

I use `sys_refcursor` to match your requirement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Pkg_test
AS

   PROCEDURE info (p_cur           IN OUT sys_refcursor,
                   p_parameter_1          NUMBER,
                   p_parameter_2          NUMBER,
                   p_parameter_3          VARCHAR2,
                   p_parameter_4          VARCHAR2,
                   p_parameter_5          NUMBER,
                   p_parameter_6          VARCHAR2);


   FUNCTION QR_2RefCurDS           
      return sys_refcursor;
END Pkg_test;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY  Pkg_test 
as 
  PROCEDURE info(p_cur  IN  OUT   sys_refcursor
               ,p_parameter_1        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_2        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_3        VARCHAR2
               ,p_parameter_4        VARCHAR2
               ,p_parameter_5        NUMBER
               ,p_parameter_6        VARCHAR2)
  IS    
   BEGIN

        OPEN p_cur FOR 
        SELECT p_parameter_1,p_parameter_2,p_parameter_3,p_parameter_4,p_parameter_5        
        FROM dual   ;                        

   EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN      
      dbms_output.put_line('In exception');
       open p_cur for 
       SELECT null,null,null,null,null 
       --bulk collect into p_cur
       FROM dual WHERE 1=0;

   End;          
  --Function Starting 
 FUNCTION QR_2RefCurDS 
 return sys_refcursor 
 is
  c1  sys_refcursor;   
 begin
   info(c1 
     ,p_parameter_1 =>  1         --:P_PARAM1
     ,p_parameter_2 =>  2         --:P_PARAM2
     ,p_parameter_3 =>  'Hello'   --:P_PARAM3
     ,p_parameter_4 =>  'Howru' --:P_PARAM4
     ,p_parameter_5 =>   4         --:P_PARAM5
     ,p_parameter_6 =>  'BYE'     --:P_PARAM6
     );
  return c1;     
end;

END Pkg_test;
```

Execution

```
SQL>  select PKG_TEST.QR_2RefCurDS from dual;

QR_2REFCURDS
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

       :B5        :B4 :B3                              :B2                                     :B1
---------- ---------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- ----------
         1          2 Hello                            Howru                                     4
```